# There is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Tags: postgresql-9.5

Table **copy_shop**
Column **data** has type  **jsonb**

If exist record with `data.name = myStore` then I need to update record. Else I need insert json.

```
{
    "name": "myStore",
    "coords": {
        "lat": "47.123456",
        "lon": "35.7890"
    }
}
```

I try this:

```
INSERT INTO copy_shop (data) 
VALUES 
('{
    "name": "myStore",
    "coords": {
        "lat": "47.123456",
        "lon": "35.7890"
    }
}')
ON CONFLICT ((data->'name')) 
DO UPDATE SET data = copy_shop.data || '{
    "name": "myStore",
    "coords": {
        "lat": "47.123456",
        "lon": "35.7890"
    }
}'::jsonb
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
SQL state: 42P10
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the error message tells you, you are missing a unique constraint (or index).

```
create unique index unique_shop_name on copy_shop ( (data ->> 'name') );
```

Note I used `->>` to get the name as a text value not as a jsonb value. You need to use the same expression in the `on conflict` clause. You also don't need to repeat the input value in the `UPDATE` part:

```
INSERT INTO copy_shop (data) 
VALUES 
('{
    "name": "myStore",
    "coords": {
        "lat": "47.123456",
        "lon": "35.7890"
    }
}')
ON CONFLICT ( (data ->> 'name') ) 
DO UPDATE 
  SET data = copy_shop.data || excluded.data;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f71708e4a0d1c35cde17f3e05aa3550e)